# Ionic 2 Card IO plugin - Scan()

Tags: ios, cordova, angular, data-binding, ionic2

**Summary**

I am using the Card IO Cordova plugin within my Ionic 2 project. It scans correctly and allows for manual entry. When I enter my information, I set the values from the scan/manual entry to the data binding values that appear in my template. The card holder name, card number redacted, and cvv all bind back to my template where I have the card details on display for confirmation. However, the Expiration Date, Expiration Year, and Postal Code do not appear to be binding.

**For example:**

```
---template---
-not working
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="postalCode"></ion-input> 

-working
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="redactedCardNumber"></ion-input> 

---component controller---
goCardIO() {
    console.log("hello")
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      CardIO.canScan().then((res: boolean) => {
        if (res) {
          let options = {
            requireCardholderName: true,
            requireExpiry: true,
            requireCCV: true,
            requirePostalCode: true,
            scanInstructions: "Scan the front of your card",
            scanExpiry: true,
            scanCardHolderName: true,
            guideColor: '#12be76',
            hideCardIOLogo: true
          };
          CardIO.scan(options).then((data) => {
            this.setCardData(data);
            console.log("CONSOLEEEE   >>>>>> " + data.postalCode)
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
            // An error occurred
          });
        }

      });
    });

  }

  setCardData(data: any) {
    this.cardObj = data;
    this.cardHolderName = data.cardholderName;
    this.cvv = data.cvv;
    this.redactedCardNumber = data.redactedCardNumber;
    this.cardNumber = data.cardNumber;

    // Nothing happening here apparently?
    this.expiryMonth =  data.expiryMonth;
    this.expiryYear = data.expiryYear;
    this.postalCode = data.postalCode;
  }
```

**Conclusion:**

I call goCardIO(). It opens the scanner. It scans the card. I enter the extra required info. I hit next. I then set the 'data' in setCardData() to the values that I bind to the template. I just can't figure out why postalCode doesn't work but redactedCardNumber does. In addition, I can only test this plugin in the device, and I can't seem to get any console logs to appear in xCode.

**My Guesses**

For a second I assumed my ios build just wasn't updating. But then I played around with some labels in the template and they updated. So that shouldn't be it. However, I have console logs appearing elsewhere, but the new ones I have placed in goCardIO() are not printing.

Am I simply accessing the wrong fields 'data' object?

Answer (score 0):

I Got It. after Scan you will get this data:

```
{"cardType":"MasterCard","redactedCardNumber":"•••• •••• •••• 1111","cardNumber":"4111111111111111","expiryMonth":2,"expiryYear":2021,"postalCode":"1233","cardholderName":"javier"}
```

but you will not get CVV. you'll have to write Cvv for securities reasons

This is my options:

```
let options = {
        requireCardholderName: true,
        requireExpiry: true,
        requireCCV: true,
        requirePostalCode: true,
        scanInstructions: "Escanee la parte frontal de su Tarjeta",
        scanExpiry: true,
        scanCardHolderName: true,
        keepApplicationTheme:true,
        guideColor: '#12be76',
        hideCardIOLogo: true,
        useCardIOLogo:false,
    };
```